# Not able to install Nvidia drivers even if PPA is setup

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, graphics, ppa

As per subject I'm trying to install the drivers version 455 on Ubuntu 20.04.
I have enabled the ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

And I can see the drivers as package `nvidia-graphics-drivers-455`.
But when I try to install them with

```
ema@scv:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-graphics-drivers-455
```

I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package nvidia-graphics-drivers-455
```

Output of `update` and `dist-upgrade`

```
ema@scv:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt dist-upgrade 
Hit:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lutris-team/lutris/ubuntu focal InRelease                                    
Hit:7 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease                                                                     
Hit:8 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu focal InRelease                                                                       
Hit:9 https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease 
Reading package lists... Done                           
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up-to-date.
N: Skipping acquisition of configured file 'contrib/binary-i386/Packages', as repository 'https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/debian focal InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 0 not to upgrade.
```

Now I'm getting the package `nvidia-driver-455`, but it tells me the following:

```
ema@scv:~$ sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 nvidia-driver-455 : Depends: libnvidia-gl-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-dkms-455 (<= 455.23.04-1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-dkms-455 (>= 455.23.04) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-kernel-source-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-extra-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-compute-utils-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-decode-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-encode-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: nvidia-utils-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-cfg1-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-ifr1-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Depends: libnvidia-fbc1-455 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
                     Recommends: libnvidia-compute-455:i386 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-decode-455:i386 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-encode-455:i386 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-ifr1-455:i386 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-fbc1-455:i386 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
                     Recommends: libnvidia-gl-455:i386 (= 455.23.04-0ubuntu0~0.20.04.1)
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Not sure what's going on.
Has anyone any Idea why this would happen?

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get this `nvidia-graphics-drivers-455`?

Comment: Is `sudo apt-get update` running without errors?  show us please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original issue is because if one has multiple entries of

```
ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
```

In the global ppa list, it may not display `nvidia-driver-455`.
After that got cleaned, I was able to see the meta package.

It would not install because I had version *450*, hence the following commands did the trick:

```
sudo apt remove nvidia-driver-450
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
```

And now it's all fine.

The first issue (duplicate ppa entry) made me go crazy for a while.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:

```
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```

after reboot the XOrg driver was active. Now i selected the 455 driver in the SoftwareUpdater and that installed and activated the 455 driver.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was to manually remove every single *CURRENT VERSION* of the packages that have `but it is not going to be installed` status.

So I had driver version 440. I had to remove `sudo apt purge libnvidia-gl-440` and so on for all of them. After that the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

The correct command is

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-455
```

Comment: Which ppa should have it? Looks like is not listed also?

Comment: The PPA you've added has it.